# Overlap an element inside relative positioned div with overflow auto using only CSS (no JS)

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am trying to overlap an element that is inside another div with `position relative` and `overflow auto`. My goal is to overlap this element over this parent div keeping the exact style for parent div and using only `CSS but no JS`.

**HTML Structure**

```
<div class="parent" style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 400px; background: red; overflow-x: auto;">
    <div class="children" style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 200px; background: green;">
        <div class="element" style="position: absolute; width: 50px; height: 750px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need this `element` div to overlap over `parent` div.

I am also sharing codepen link to have an idea, and if it can be modified over there: [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdMKmE?editors=1100)

*blue box [**element div**] need to be overlapped over all the parent divs when hovered*

Hope the information I am providing is explanatory and if anything more needed please let me know.

---

Few more briefing:

`What's happening`
[what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f30c.png)

`What's expecting`
[What's expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTWFp.png)

---

`HTML in codepen`

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.children {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.75);
}

.children:last-child {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.75);
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.75);
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
  z-index: 100;
}

.element:hover {
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok so when you hover on `blue-box` you need to overlap all your other boxes with it ?

Comment: No, I only need the `blue-box` to overlap the `children` and `parent` div. No-other box needs to be overlapped.

Comment: only one parent or all the parents ? your question is not explain in brief

Comment: I mean the parent with class name `parent`

Comment: And the div with class name `parent` mean it will overlap both `parent` and `children` named class. Hope it clears.

Comment: okk and also not overflow ?

Comment: No, overflow-y will not be there. Overflow-x will be like what it is now for `children` and `parent` div. Wait will update the question with an image (what I am expecting).

Comment: Please refer to the images for better understanding